# Quantitative study of time between signature and ratification of multilateral economic treaties

Tags: economy, international-law, treaty, reference-request

Does anyone know of a good quantitative study of economic multilateral treaties that specifically looks at how much time passes between the date of signature and date of ratification/accession? I have found studies on individual country's practices, but am having trouble finding a comprehensive study of countries in general in relation to multilateral economic treaties.

I am looking for a cross-national or a comparative study of the treaty practices across countries.

Comment: Is there anything in particular the study should look for? Or are you looking for a general pros and cons list (in the form of a study)?

Comment: I am looking for more of a general study that is cross-national or a comparative study of the treaty practices across countries.

Comment: That's still too broad/unclear in my opinion.

Comment: I narrowed it. I am new to this area of study and have had trouble finding even related studies which is why I initially asked it in the broad sense.